# Can you calculate a global array (instance member) before passing it to another class?

Tags: java, arrays, instance

I created two classes. They both work together.  Simply, once you execute the 'Main' class, one global array (instance member) called 'public static int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};' from the 'NewClass1' class, passes over to the 'Main' class.  In the 'Main' class, it outputs the number five. This specifies that there are five numbers from the 'a' array (NewClass1).

The issue is that once you alter the int array from the 'Main' class, using the 'int e = NewClass1.d.length;' instead of the other array, 'int e = NewClass1.a.length;' it outputs the number one. That is where I get lost.  I would say that the answer should be five, similar to the original answer. The only understanding I get would be that all the global arrays in the NewClass1 class get executed first, meaning passing the arrays from the beginning of the program to the other class. This does not have enough time to store anything from the calculations in the main program below.

Would that be right? If so, would there be a way to make the global array  'public static int[] d[] = {b};' to be calculated before being passed over to the other class 'Main'?

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main (String[]args)
        {
        int e = NewClass1.a.length;
        //int e = NewClass1.d.length;
        System.out.println (e);
        }
    }


    import java.util.*;
    public class NewClass1 
    {
        public static int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        public static int[] b = new int[5];
        public static int[] d[] = { b };

        public static void main (String[]args)
        {
            System.out.println ("TEST");
            for (int c = 0; c < a.length; c++)
            {
            b[c] = a[c] + 7;
            }
            System.out.println ("New numbers: " + Arrays.toString (b));

        }
    }
```

Comment: `d` is a two dimensional array. What happens when any object (or array) is stored in a two dimensional array as its element?

Comment: `a` is _not_ an instance member. It is called as class or static member.

Comment: Hi prasad_,  ok, makes sense with the two dimensional array.  So 'b' is the first array in the 'd' two dimensional array.  That's why I get the output one in the 'Main' class. I am wondering how is it possible in opening the 'd' array in the 'Main' class to find out what's inside 'b' array?

Comment: See if this helps [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: @prasad_ I looked at the web you sent me. It was ok, but no way of passing the static member.  So I searched some more info on passing 2D arrays.  I stumbled upon one web but would not work well,  unless I did not see the code well.  I will check it once more.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205901/passing-a-2d-array-into-another-class-java